# Command found at the command line but not in script

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to create a new [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) project using a script on mac. For this, I followed the following steps:

1. Add `PATH` of tools and platform-tools in my `.bash_profile`
2. Verify that the `android` command works in the shell.
3. Write a script to create a new project.

Here is the script I wrote:

```
NAME=$1
PATH=$2
PACKAGE=$3

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3

function create_new_android_project()
{
android create project -n "$NAME" -t 7 -p "$PATH" -k "$PACKAGE" -a MainActivity
}


create_new_android_project
echo
echo "******** Complete!!!"
```

The `android` command runs in the shell. But when I run the script with
**sh script.sh project_name project_path package_name**
it gives up with an error saying `android: command not found`.

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` variable has a special meaning to the shell. The shell expects it to contain a colon separated list of directories where it can look for programs, when you do not supply a complete path for them.

To solve your problem, use another name than `PATH` in your program.

As a general advice, I invite you to use a stronger discipline quoting arguments and avoiding the `echo` command:

1. There is few reasons why a variable name should not appear between double quotes. Therefore, unless you want to achieve something special, you should always use double quotes to control variable expansion.
2. Prefer `printf` over `echo` because it is easier to use, more reliable and more portable (also, a clear winner).